# Match image paths with skus (Magento)

Tags: magento

I have about 2k product images that need to be matched with the product sku in order to be imported into magento.

The problem is sometimes the image names do not match the product sku exactly. Usually there is a hyphen or a capital letter or maybe even an extra letter that throws it off.

What is the best way to match the product images with the product skus without going through each image name one by one?

Comment: First idea is to remove all "hyphen" or other 100 percent unneccessary chars from the string. Then I would create a small skript, which compares the file name maybe with `levenshtein()` function. The levenshtein distance is good for comparing similar strings :) - http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.levenshtein.php

Comment: thanks I show this to a programmer and hopefully he can work something out.